# How can I get a top border tight to a font's glyphs?

Tags: css, border, typography

I have need in a project to show rules at the baseline, x-height, and cap height of several font samples.  I have baseline and x-height taken care of, but am having trouble getting a general CSS rule that will draw a border at the cap height of any font I apply the rule to.  I've fiddled with the line height, but the space between a font's glyphs and the top of its layout box differs from font to font, so setting it once won't work for any font.

This Code Pen example illustrates the issue:  http://codepen.io/DrSpatula/pen/BAgqG

Comment: maybe this article will help you: http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/improve_your_web_typography_with_baseline_shift/ or this: http://css-infos.net/property/alignment-baseline

Comment: I think that a great solution to your problem is `font-size-adjust` but again it lacks compatibility. http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/fonts.html#propdef-font-size-adjust

Comment: Can you use :after{} and set an absolutely positioned 100% width 1px high element to be top:-1px; background:black; ?

Answer (score 1):

You are now applying the line-height to the p. If you remove it there, and apply the line-height to the span.text, and set it to a value of 1.55ex, it shows properly.

So your CSS will be:

```
    p {
      font-size: 72px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    p span {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .sans {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .text { 
      border-top: 1px solid blue;
      line-height: 1.55ex;
    }

    .rule {
      height: 1ex;
      border-top: 1px dotted red;
      border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
      position: relative;
      left: -7.25em;
      width: 7.75em;
      top: 1px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very dirty, but have you tried a one pixel .gif as a repeating background then you can set it's position relative to the font?

Answer (score 0):

maybe I can help.
I've made a small fiddle for you to view.
(http://jsfiddle.net/dgxJh/1/)

I fear however that with this solution you'll have to repostion the span with the pink line for every font-size and every font.
But in essence you'll position a span over your text by using following code:

```
span{
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background: pink;    
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.6em;
}
```

don't forget to position your container relative